# Obtaining drop-down values and displaying them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble making the value obtained by the drop down to display. I just started learning JS yesterday... Cheers! 
[eta] The question is what is wrong with my code, as it is not working as I want it to.

```
<!doctype html>
<html><body>
<script src="jquery.js">

$(function checkDropdown() {
var selects= $("#id1 option:selected").val();
document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML= selects;
});
</script>

<form name="f1">
<select id="id1">
<OPTION Value="none">None</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="one">One</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="two">Two</OPTION>
</select></form>
<p id="filler">Replace this text</p>
</br></br>
<button onClick="checkDropdown()">  CLICK ME  </button>
</form>
</body></html>
```

I ultimately want to then replace the option values with actual numbers and multiplying them.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please review the [faq]. As it stands you haven't asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your jQuery. Try this:

```
var selects= $("#id1").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all wrong.

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
function checkDropdown() {
  var selects= $("#id1").val();
  $("#filler").text(selects);
}
</script>

<form name="f1">
<select id="id1">
<OPTION Value="none">None</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="one">One</OPTION>
<OPTION Value="two">Two</OPTION>
</select></form>
<p id="filler">Replace this text</p>
</br></br>
<button onClick="checkDropdown()">  CLICK ME  </button>
</form>
</body></html>
```

1. You should create two script tags. 1 in which you load jquery, 2 in which you define your own code.
2. You don't need to use :selected selector, since dropdown value always equals the value of the selected option.
3. Don't mix document.getElementById() with jQuery. It's much better to stick with one method.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a function to `$`, it will be executed *when the DOM is ready*. But that is not what you want here. You want the function to be called whenever the button is clicked, so don't pass it to `$`:

```
<script>
    function checkDropdown() {
        // Simplified version of your code
        var selects = $('#id1').val();
        $('#filler').text(selects);
    }
</script>
```

You can further improve your code by binding the event handler using jQuery and not with inline event handlers.

[Read more about `$`, alias `jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3). I also recommend to read the [jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery), which explains everything you need to know to get you started with event handlers (and jQuery in general).

Lastly, if you want to learn how events work really work, read the [articles at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

---

Didn't notice this first: You have to load jQuery in it's own script tag.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Again, read the tutorial, these things are all covered there.

Comment: This did the trick, it would seem I was not using the right commands either.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have other issues with your code, because of how the function is being declared.
Check this answer for some more information on how to define functions in jquery.
[Is this how you define a function in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907634/is-this-how-you-define-a-function-in-jquery)

Just a little bit of rearranging makes it work on my end.

```
checkDropdown = function() {
  var selects= $("#id1 option:selected").val();
  document.getElementById("filler").innerHTML= selects;
};​
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/kjmuE/