# making a jquery function to return elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I m making a jquery function to return elements.

Basically without the function i m writing code as the follows which introduces html line breaks in place text with line breaks.

```
var $li = $('ol#update > li');

$li.each(function(i, e) {

    var $txt = $(e).find('.com_msg_text');

    var txt = $txt.html();          

    txt = line_break(txt);

    $txt.html(   txt  );

});
```

Now I m writing a function to do the same -

```
function test() {

    $(this).each(function(i, e) {

        $(e).html( line_break($(e).html()  ) );

    });
    return this;
}
```

and i m calling it through -

```
 $('ol#update li').find('.com_msg_text').test();
```

But this does not run and gives the error

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Comment: you never defined `test` on the jquery prototype.

Answer (score 1):

The `jQuery` prototype does not have a function called `test`. This is why you're getting the error message.

You want to use [`jQuery.fn.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/) to extend the jQuery prototype and create your own `test` function:

```
$.fn.test = function() {
    return this.each(function(i, e) {
        $(e).html( line_break($(e).html()) );
    });           
}
```

`each` is already chainable, so you don't have to explicitly return `this`.

Comment: I know but still whats the use of wrapping function inside (function($) { ... })(jQuery);

Comment: It's for encapsulation. You're ensuring that you're not polluting the global namespace with local variables, or even a named function. This is known as an immediately-invoked function-expression.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22961306/1584112) for more details on how to extend jQuery prototype.

Comment: This answer is not helpful at all. Don't simply link to other answers. It's doubly worse that you're simply linking to your own answer without any further explanation.

Comment: @VivinPaliath why is function wrapped inside (function($)
{  ... })(jQuery); I can run without that.

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya That's not my answer. Take a look at the [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24663767/263004) I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Now if i use only jQuery.fn.extend -

```
jQuery.fn.extend({ 
   test: function() {
      return this.each(function() {         
         this.innerHTML = line_break(this.innerHTML);
    });    
}

});
```

Same way using jQuery -

```
jQuery.fn.extend({ 
  test: function() {
     return this.each(function(i, e) {         
        $(e).html ( line_break($(e).html()) );
   });    
  }
});
```